# How do I remove a purchase event that is being output in my HTML via Google Tag Manager?

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager

Since a view days, Google Tag Manager outputs a purchase event into my html. The output looks like some sample data from development. I have no idea why this is shown underneath the footer of my page.

Has anyone an idea where this can come from?

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', { 'transaction_id': 't_12345', 'currency': 'USD', 'value': 1.23, user_data: { email_address: 'johnsmith@email.com', phone_number: '1234567890', address: { first_name: 'john', last_name: 'smith', city: 'menlopark', region: 'ca', postal_code: '94025', country: 'usa', }, }, items: [{ item_name: 'foo', quantity: 5, price: 123.45, item_category: 'bar', item_brand : 'baz', }], });
```

I have commeted out the Google Tag Manager code in my index.html and the output has disapeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely happens because someone published that code in a custom html trigger, but forgot to add the `<script>` tag around the code.

The fact that this was published and never even tested indicates that someone does work that they're not qualified for.

To remove it, find recently added custom html tags in GTM, then pause the tag that has the code you quoted and then go test if the issue persists. If it stops, you've found your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I didn't know that this could be injected from a GTM configuration.

Comment: Yes, GTM has the ability to evaluate arbitrary JS in the global scope of a page it's loaded on. As such, it definitely can manipulate DOM.